# React : Grab change on input value done by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Not a fan of mixing jQuery with React but I liked a color picker called Farbstastic so I embedded it as a component in my React app. There is an **input field** as type **hidden** where the **value** gets changed when user interact the with color picker. **I want to grab the value in React using onChange event.**

[image]

This is my react code to grab the change:

```
class Color extends Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <label htmlFor="color">Color:</label>

                <input type="hidden" id="color" name="color" value="#123456"  onChange={event => { console.log(event.target.value);} }/>
                <div id="picker"></div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is it does not grab the change on **value** by jQuery.

Comment: Maybe problem on your code .
change onChange={event => { console.log(event.target.value);} }
to onChange="{event => { console.log(event.target.value);} }"

Comment: doesn't work. stays the same.

Comment: "Setting values using `val` method (or using the native value property) does not cause the dispatch of the change event. For this reason, the relevant event handlers will not be executed. If you want to execute them, you should call .trigger( "change" ) after setting the value."  

From the official jq docs.

Answer (score 1):

You use case is called uncontrolled components in react world.
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

So basically you have to use `ref` to access value of this input in your react class methods.

```
      <input type="hidden" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" 
        ref={(input) => this.colorCodeInput = input}/>
      <div id="picker"></div>
```

Now in your submit function you can access the value set like

```
onSubmit() {
  let colorCode = this.colorCodeInput.value.
}
```

Comment: Did you understand what OP want? OP is able to change the value of the input field. But how to capture the event when some one change the value of the hidden field. He tried to use onChange but it not getting triggered. He is asking how to capture that event? Is your answer resolving that issue?

Comment: yep this method will work only if he wants to access the input value in a submit function. Not on onchange event

Comment: @Subin this actually works. but I have one more question how to make the form submit automatically because clicking a button every time color has been changed using the color picker is not a viable solution.

Comment: Is your onChange code executed when you choose color `onChange={event => { console.log(event.target.value);} }/ `